# Android Call Function from another class without static

Tags: android, function, class

Okay, I have been searching for a few days now, and I can't seem to find an simple method for calling one function from another class. I have Active.java and Finished.Java. What I want to do is from Finished.java call run_now(); from Active.java. Eventually I will be calling information from a php/mysql server so I can not make any of these functions static. Any help is great.. Thanks

```
public class Finished extends Activity
{   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.finished_page);

    Log.i("Info:", "Finished");
            run_now();
}
}

public class Active extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.finished_page);

    Log.i("Info:", "Active");
}

    public class run_now extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
           @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() 
       {
           super.onPreExecute();   
       }

           protected void onPostExecute(String result)
       {

           }

           @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
       {
                 // DO SOMETHING HERE
           }
}
}
```

Comment: create an instance of object of the class Active and call the method will it is not a method but a inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't have any static functions you could wrap this code in simple public function in Active.java called run for example

```
    public void run()
    {
       new run_now().execute();
    }
```

then you can make an object of your Active.java class in Finished.java OnCreate() and call run.

```
    Active active=new Active();
    active.run();
```

Comment: Couple questions. Does Active active=new Active(); go in the Finished.java? Or in the Active.java? Also when I put it in either and try to do the new active.run_now().execute(); it says active can not be resolved to a type.

Comment: Thanks so much.. This makes it all so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the method static, as long as you pass your current Context in.

Comment: Making it static would cause more errors down the line when I add in my http and nameValuePairs stuff. So trying to avoid that.